# Powershell FileSystemWatcher network drive stops working. Need resetting?

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher, network-drive

I have a FileSystemWatcher program in PowerShell that is supposed to run on a server as long as the server is on. The program is started when the server starts. The FSW is supposed to run a program each time a new file is added to the folder it is watching, which is on a network drive. But for some reason, it doesn't execute the "action" program after some time. After a restart, the program works fine, running the "action" each time a new file arrives. I have not been able to find a clear pattern - it seems to stop responding, sometimes after a day, other times after just one "firing" of the action program.

I suspect this is because I am watching a file on a network drive, which according to other threads on stackoverflow, is unreliable and might need resetting: [FileSystemWatcher stops catching events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184115/filesystemwatcher-stops-catching-events)

The provided link sovles it in C#, so I wonder if a similar resetting could be written in Powershell?

Here is the program I am trying to run. I am working on a try catch for the fsw, but from what I have gathered so far, the problem must likely be solved by resetting if the network connection is interrupted.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$action  = "someprogram.ps1"

function log($string, $color, $logfile)
{
   if ($Color -eq $null) {$color = 'white'}
   write-host $string -foregroundcolor $color
   $string | out-file -Filepath $logfile -append
}


$folder = "somefolder"
$filter = '*.csv'  


$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property 
    @{
     IncludeSubdirectories = $false             
     NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
     }

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action 
        {  
        $global:FilePath = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        $time = get-date
        log -String "File $FilePath detected at $time" -logfile $logfile
        & $action 
        }
```

I am thinking a solution like this would be preferred to running a C# code:

```
while (Test-Path -Path $folder)
{
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 #to reduce cpu load
##FileSystemWatcher code here
}
##Somehow restart file watcher if connection is lost
```

However, I dont want the script to run again every second or so. So I am thinking I might have to have another script running in parralell that checks if the folder path exists, and upon a disconnect, run a

```
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated
```

and then restart the script. Then again, what happens if the connection to the folder is broken for one millisecond, while my script is sleeping? In that case, the test-path will not notice anything, and the script will fail as the filewatcher will no longer be able to detect a new file

Comment: Any C# program can run in PowerShell.  Obviously you can compile it to `.exe` and run it.  Or you can load an assembly directly into PS.

Comment: I am also struggling with this and cannot determine how to do this without calling C# from PowerShell.  The most important piece we need from C# is something like `fsw.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnErrorMethod);`